# Using data-attributes and using them for a XML HTTP Request

Tags: javascript, dom

I have this button with a data attribute called "data-id" and its value is "1". The 1 is the id number for a car in my database.

```
 <div class="row">
   <button type="button" class="btn" data-id="1">View Car Details</button>
 </div>
```

When it's clicked I want to pass this id to my JavaScript where it will send this id to my PhP using XMLHttpRequest. This is what I have for the JavaScript

```
 <script>
        const buttons = document.querySelectorAll("[data-id]");
        buttons.forEach(button => {
            button.addEventListener("click", (loadCarDetails));
        });
        document.getElementById('car-details').addEventListener('click', loadCarDetails);

        function loadCarDetails() {
            let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();


            xhr.open('GET', 'getCarDetails.php', true);
            xhr.onload = function () {
                if (this.status == 200) {
                    let carDetails = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
                    console.log(cars);

                   
                    //document.getElementById('users').innerHTML = output;
                }
            }
            xhr.send();
        }
    </script>
```

I need to somehow get the id and pass it to the getCarDetails.php which will return the details of the car using jSON. I need to use the id to perform a query in the getCarDetails.php.
This is my PHP.

```
$connection = new mysqli("sever", "username", "password", "database");
$car_id = $_POST['car_id];
    if ($connection->connect_error){
        exit("Error connecting to the database");
    }
    mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
    $connection->set_charset("utf8mb4");
  
    $car_id = $connection->escape_string($_POST['car_id']);

   

    $stmt = $connection->prepare("SELECT car_drivetrain_lookup.drivetrain_type, car_suitability_lookup.car_suitability_type
    FROM cars
    INNER JOIN car_suitability_lookup ON car_suitability_lookup.lookup_id = cars.car_suitability_id
    INNER JOIN car_drivetrain_lookup ON car_drivetrain_lookup.lookup_id = cars.car_drivetrain_id
    WHERE cars.car_id = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param("i", $car_id);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    echo json_encode($result->fetch_all());
```

Can someone help me achieve this? I'm really new to JavaScript and would like to be pointed in the right direction.

Comment: Side note: There's no reason for the `()` around `loadCarDetails` in `button.addEventListener("click", (loadCarDetails));`, just `button.addEventListener("click", loadCarDetails);` is all you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two aspects to this:

1. Getting the `id` from the clicked element, and
2. Sending the correct kind of request to the server

The first part is simple. Your `loadCarDetails` function is called with an event object as the first argument, which has a `currentTarget` property referring to the element you hooked the function to, so we can get the `data-*` attribute from that:

```
function loadCarDetails(event) {
    const id = event.currentTarget.getAttribute("data-id");
    // ...
}
```

Then we need to do a `POST` (your current code does a `GET` instead) with that `id` as `car_id`. I wouldn't use `XMLHttpRequest` in new code, it's outdated; I'd use [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/fetch):

```
function loadCarDetails(event) {
    const id = event.currentTarget.getAttribute("data-id");
    const body = new FormData();
    body.append("car_id", id);
    fetch("getCarDetails.php", {
        method: "POST",
        body
    })
    .then(response => {
        if (!response.ok) {
            throw new Error(`HTTP error ${response.status}`);
        }
        return response.json();
    })
    .then(carDetails => {
        // ...use the car details here...
    })
    .catch(error => {
        // ...handle/reject error here...
    });
}
```

Comment: Hi TJ. I've tried running this code but nothing is happening. I've even tried to console.log(carDetails) and nothing happens when I click the button.

Comment: Do you have any idea why this might not be working?

Comment: @GeorgeAustinBradley - There was a minor error in the above (was using the property name `data`, not `body`, for the body of the POST). I fixed that and tried it locally and it works just fine.